# Laravel 5 – get particular many to many relation based on model and related model ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got `Tag` and `Attendee` Eloquent models, they are in many-to-many relation. Pivot table has also two more attributes – `value_int` and `value_string`. My `Attendee` model looks like this:

```
class Attendee extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'event_id'
    ];

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tag', 'attendee_tag', 'attendee_id', 'tag_id')
            ->withPivot(['value_string', 'value_int']);
    }

    public function scoreTagValue($tag_id) {
        return $this->tags->where('tag_id', '=', $tag_id)->first();
    }

}
```

What I want is to obtain pivot values based on `Attendee` model and variable `tag_id`, so I've written `scoreTagValue` function, but it always returns `null` and I don't know why :( I'm calling it this way:
`$attendee->scoreTagValue($tag_id)`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: no, the tag value, I'm looking for, is called score :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the relation, not the property:

```
public function scoreTagValue($tag_id) {
    return $this->tags()->where('tag_id', '=', $tag_id)->first();
}
```

Also, [according to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), `withPivot()` does not take an array, so:

```
->withPivot('value_string', 'value_int');
```

Comment: Actually I don't think this is correct - did it help?

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting tags, but without pivot data :)

Comment: without change, still getting only related Tag models without pivot data :(

Comment: maybe should help, that when I obtain tag this way, I'm not able to access its attributes... I tried `tag->id` and got – Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: pivot fields are accessible like `tag->pivot->value_string`.  Can you try dumping what you get back, eg `dd($attendee->scoreTagValue($tag_id))`?

Comment: ah, I've got `$hidden` pivot in Tag model :) thank you very much :) Now it works :)